# Custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm working on a image class-incremental classifier approach using a CNN as a feature extractor and a fully-connected block for classifying.

First, I did a fine-tuning of a VGG per-trained network to do a new task. Once the net is trained for the new task, i store some examples for every class in order to avoid forgetting when new classes are available.

When some classes are available, i have to compute every output of the exemplars included the exemplars for the new classes. Now adding zeros to the outputs for old classes and adding the label corresponding to each new class on the new classes outputs i have my new labels, i.e:
if 3 new classes enter....

Old class type output: `[0.1, 0.05, 0.79, ..., 0 0 0]`

New class type output: `[0.1, 0.09, 0.3, 0.4, ..., 1 0 0]` **the last outputs correspond to the class.

My question is, how i can change the loss function for a custom one to train for the new classes?
The loss function that i want to implement is defined as:

[image: loss function]

where distillation loss corresponds to the outputs for old classes to avoid forgetting, and classification loss corresponds to the new classes.

If you can provide me a sample of code to change the loss function in keras would be nice.

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

All you have to do is define a function for that, using keras backend functions for calculations. The function must take the true values and the model predicted values.

Now, since I'm not sure about what are g, q, x an y in your function, I'll just create a basic example here without caring about what it means or whether it's an actual useful function:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    return K.sum(K.log(yTrue) - K.log(yPred))
```

All backend functions can be seen [here](https://keras.io/backend/#backend-functions).

After that, compile your model using that function instead of a regular one:

```
model.compile(loss=customLoss, optimizer = .....)
```

Comment: okaay, that is exactly what i was looking for, Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Daniel So how does keras map the custom loss function arguments? Does it take the model outputs and apply them implicitly to the customLoss? Like CustomLoss(*model_outputs)?

Comment: `custom_loss(y_train_converted_to_tensor, model_outputs_tensor)`

Comment: Even though custom loss functions only take the target and prediction as inputs, it seems we can use other Tensors, too, with a trick: ```def customLoss1(yTrue, yPred):
    return mse(inputInterm, yPred)``` This captures the Tensor, `inputInterm` in this case. It seems to work for me, though I haven't seen it used. Does anyone see any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: @flow2k, this works, no problem. It might bring you a problem when you want to save and load this model, because this tensor will not be a part of it. So, in order to do that more safely, you should have a layer to handle this tensor properly. Either a custom layer that creates it, or an `Input(tensor=...)` layer.

Comment: @DanielMöller I definitely need to checkpoint and reload in training, so thanks for bring this up. Hmm, I think there's something I'm not understanding about checkpointing. I usually do `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(...save_weights_only=True)`; this saves the parameters of the model (like bias and scaling factors in Dense layers), as I understand. The Tensors, being inputs and outputs to the layers, are not saved, right? Because why would we need to? Don't they get computed based on the inputs in training and inference?

Comment: It all depends on "what" your tensors are. If you're saving/loading only weights, you're fine, you're code will be entirely preserved, naturally.

Comment: Side question: is it true the custom loss function can return a 1-D vector? I'm looking at this and it seems to be the case: https://github.com/twairball/keras_lstm_vae/blob/master/lstm_vae/vae.py#L77-L81. In it, `x` is a 2-D matrix. If I'm reading https://keras.io/losses/ correctly, if a vector is passed as the loss, Keras will just take the mean of the loss vector to arrive at a scalar loss.

Comment: Yes, it's probably recommended that you return all samples. Keras will do some extra things like applying sample weights when they are defined, for instance.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks for your answer here. Can you answer a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566096/custom-loss-function-that-updates-at-each-step

Answer (score 5):

**Since Keras is not multi-backend anymore ([source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0)), operations for custom losses should be made directly in Tensorflow, rather than using the backend.**

You can make a custom loss with Tensorflow by making a function that takes `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments, as suggested in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/losses/#creating-custom-losses):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(10, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(10, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

custom_mse(x, y)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.30084264, 0.03535452, 0.10345092, 0.28552982, 0.02426687,
       0.04410492, 0.01701574, 0.55496216, 0.74927425, 0.05747304],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Then you can set your custom loss in `model.compile()`. Here's a complete example:

```
x = tf.random.uniform(minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(1000, 4), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.multiply(tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=-1), 5) # y is a function of x

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=[4], activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=custom_mse, optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)
```

```
Train on 1000 samples
Epoch 1/5
  32/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 99.5402
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 371us/sample - loss: 105.6800
Epoch 2/5
  32/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 89.2909
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 35us/sample - loss: 98.8208
Epoch 3/5
  32/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 86.4339
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 34us/sample - loss: 82.7988
Epoch 4/5
  32/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 75.2580
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 33us/sample - loss: 52.4585
Epoch 5/5
  32/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 28.1625
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 34us/sample - loss: 17.8190
```

Comment: So the accepted answer returns a scalar from the custom loss function, but your answer returns a (10,) tensor (which clearly seems to work). Are we really free to do either, or is the accepted answer incorrect, or is either a valid return from the custom loss function?