# keras flow and backpropagation

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence

I cannot find anywhere how exactly is backpropagation done in Keras? Let me explain:

Lets say i have network

```
input = Input(shape=(X,X,Y))
x = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding="same")(input)
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding="same")(x)
x = Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding="same")(x)
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding="same")(x)
Output = Flatten(1024)(x)
Output = Flatten(6)(Output)
model = Model(input,Output)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainingData,trainingLabels)
```

The output of last layer is compared to `trainingLabels`, `mean squared error` is computed and Backpropagation happens based on the value of `mean squaed error`

However, what if i wanted to something more. And for example I want to try every permutation of output vector, and the one that results in minimal `mean squared error` should be treated as output, thus Backpropagation happens based on permutation with least error.

Is something like this possible in Keras? If so, how can i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

The `loss` argument of `model.compile` method accepts a python function. You could compute the minimum over the set of permutations in a custom function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_predicted):
    ''' code here '''
```

and then pass it to `model.compile`:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, 
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43821374) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/369) for reference.