# How can I take the elementwise log of a tensor of tensors and then multiply each tensor by different scalars in tf?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom loss function for Keras to use and I'm having some trouble.  Following this post here: [Custom loss function in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818584/custom-loss-function-in-keras/43821374) I know the syntax for creating the function, but I'm not familiar with how to work with tensors.
I filled yTrue with scalars and yPred is the actual predicted values.  I want to take the weighted sum of the logs of the predicted values, weighted by the scalars in yTrue.  When I do something like this:

```
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
        L = 0
        for i in range(len(yTrue)):
            L += tf.math.scalar_mul(yTrue[i], K.log(yPred[i]))
        return L
```

The program crashes when I try to compile the model with a custom loss function, because it seems to be passing some tensors and running the loss function when I do model.compile.  Printing out yTrue and yPred, I get `Tensor("dense_4_target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32) Tensor("dense_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32)` 
Which tells me that I have to make my custom loss function work with tensors.

I've tried `return K.sum(K.prod(yTrue,K.log(yPred)))` but I get

```
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1722, in reduce_prod
    name=name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 6239, in prod
    name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 610, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
```

which I don't find very helpful

Comment: Is this the error message you got ? Does look like though. A year back I did work with creating custom loss fn in keras. In you are customLoss you are using `tf.math` module or you do `import keras.backend as K`?

Comment: That is an error message that I got.  And I did import keras.backend as K

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.  I pass to model.fit(x=states,y=G) where G is an array that matches the size of yPred.  These are where I put the values of my scalars.  Then my loss function could just be `return K.sum(K.sum(yTrue*K.log(yPred)))`